# How to get the keys from ContentValues?

Tags: java, android

My ContentValues object has string keys, and I would like to get a String[] result having all the keys in it?

How do I iterate a ContentValues object?

**EDIT 1**

After getting two responses I came up with this, do you see problems with it?

```
        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentValues cv=data;
        Set<Entry<String, Object>> s=cv.valueSet();
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : s) {
            ar.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        String[] projection=new String[ar.size()];
        ar.toArray(projection);
```

Comment: nothing pops out, doesn't it work?

Comment: You may as well populate the array directly from the Set, rather than via the ArrayList first, but other than that, looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc, the "valueSet()" method returns a set of all keys and values.  You can then use an iterator on the resultant Set and getKey() on each of the iterated Entry elements to collect into a String array.

Answer (score 21):

Try this code. Just pass your `ContentValues` into the method.

```
public void printContentValues(ContentValues vals)
{
   Set<Entry<String, Object>> s=vals.valueSet();
   Iterator itr = s.iterator();

   Log.d("DatabaseSync", "ContentValue Length :: " +vals.size());

   while(itr.hasNext())
   {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)itr.next(); 
        String key = me.getKey().toString();
        Object value =  me.getValue();

        Log.d("DatabaseSync", "Key:"+key+", values:"+(String)(value == null?null:value.toString()));
   }
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason you used `Entry` first and then `Map.Entry` later? Are they both different in this context?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one also:

```
String ar [] = {};
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    int i=0;
    for(String key: cv.keySet()){
        ar[i] = key;
    }
```